# Can we ask questions about Debian and Ubuntu-based operating systems on Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've just installed Debian alongside Ubuntu and windows 7 in other partition. since I have a problem with my Debian OS (about booting it) but I don't see an Ask Debian site and since I trust the answers from Ask Ubuntu, and Ubuntu is a derivative of Debian, I thought it might be reasonable to ask questions about Debian here.

I tried to find my answer on various forums and also on Debian support, but I didn't find it. can I ask questions about Debian and Ubuntu-based operating systems like Zorin, Mint, etc on Ask Ubuntu? If not, then where can I ask them?

I also asked the question on Quora but not a single answer has solved my problem.

Comment: you edited your question to ask about Ubuntu-based systems as well as Debian. Seth's answer also applies to those distributions (Mint, Zorin, etc).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot ask questions about Debian on Ask Ubuntu.  You can ask them on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) however.